# Expression for $\mathcal{O}_{\mathbb{P}(N_{Y/X})}(-k)$ in blowup

Tags: algebraic-geometry, blowup

Let $X$ be a smooth toric variety and $Y \subset X$ be a complete intersection with the normal bundle $N_{Y/X}$ and $E \subset \mathrm{Bl_Y X}$ be exceptional divisor. Than it is well known that $E \simeq \mathbb{P}(N_{Y/X})$ and $\mathcal{O}_{\mathbb{P}(N_{Y/X})}(-k) \simeq \mathcal{O}_{E}(E)$.

My question is:

> How to express $\mathcal{O}_{\mathbb{P}(N_{Y/X})}(-k)$ with $k > 1$ in similar terms?

Actually i want to construct a resolution of $\mathcal{O}_{\mathbb{P}(N_{Y/X})}(-k)$ like $0\to\mathcal{O} \to \mathcal{O}(E)\to \mathcal{O}_{\mathbb{P}(N_{Y/X})}(-1)\to 0$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, $O_E(E) \cong O_{\mathbb{P}(N)}(-1)$, there is no $k$ yet. From this it is clear that $O_E(kE) \cong O_{\mathbb{P}(N)}(-k)$ for any $k$, and so a possible resolution is 
$$
0 \to O((k-1)E) \to O(kE) \to O_{\mathbb{P}(N)}(-k) \to 0.
$$

Comment: This was my first thought but than i got strange a consequence:
Let X be $\mathbb{P}^1\times \mathbb{P}^1 \times\mathbb{P}^1\times\mathbb{P}^1 $ and $Y$ be two points $(1:0;1:0;1:0;1:0), (0:1;0:1;0:1;0:1)$ than i had that $\chi (\mathcal{O}(3 E)) = 9, \chi( \mathcal{O}(2 E)) = 1$ therefore using this resolution i got that $\chi(\mathcal{O}_\mathbb{P^3} (-3)) = 8$ but it should be zero.

Comment: And how did you get $\chi(O(3E)) = 9$?

Comment: it is the toric variety and $E$ is toric divisor so I compute its cohomology using macaulay2
May be I (or the program) made a mistake

Comment: @user2715119 Most probably it is your mistake.